# Is there a way to use aggregate function on excel to bring back multiple results meeting multiple criteria excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a dynamic search that brings back non-repeating data from a large dataset that meets multiple criteria.

I've put together the formula that uses index and aggregate, and then if to stop when no more results match by comparing the number to a countif of the amount of results I'm expecting.

It brings back the results meeting one criterion (business unit in my case), but I also want to have one of the fields (close date) be after a date (the starting date of the employee currently selected from a dropdown list), and before the date the report is being generated (which will be in a cell).

I basically inherited this technique from someone who left the company where he made a model to calculate commissions for sales guys, and now I've been asked to replicate it for pre-sales. Just so I have some kind of output I'm currently doing it by a power query which I haven't figured out how to make dynamic, but I have been asked to replicate it for pre-sales since it's known to work and once done, doesn't need a lot of playing around with. But the sales one only needed one field to match, and pre-sales is a bit more complicated.

I broke down his formula and got a basic understanding of how it works, and come up with this version of the formula that I've made from his (that only does one criterion) so here it is in as simple a view as I can do:

```
=IF(
    ROWS(
        $A$27:A27
    ) < $C$24,
    INDEX(
        Table2[Table ID],
        AGGREGATE(
            15,
            3,
            ( Table2[Business Unit] = $C$9 ) / ( Table2[Business Unit] = $C$9 ) * (                ROW(
                    Table2[Business Unit]
                ) -
                ROW(
                    Table2[#Headers]
                ) ),
            ROWS(
                $A$27:A27
            )
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

How can I also add in a criteria that the close date (table2[Close Date]) would be more than the start date of the employee in question (in a specific cell eg C10) and less than the date the report is being generated (eg cell C6)?

Comment: If you are trying to retrieve multiple rows where criteria in various columns are met,  set your aggregate function up to be 14 or 15 depending which sort direction you want on the row then proceed to set up you formula similar ROW ($A$1:$A$1000)/(($B$1:$B$1000="Check1)*($E$1:$E$1000="Check3")).  When all your checks are TRUE, you wind up dividing by 1.  When anyone of them is false you wind up dividing by 0 which generates an error.  With Aggregate set to ignore errors you will be left with a an array of Applicable rows.  For which instance to return use ROW(A1).  Copy it downward

Comment: So I tried to change it in line with your recommendation and I ended up with this formula that gives me a value error: =IF(
    ROWS(
        A$27:A27
    ) > $C$24,
    "",
    INDEX(
        Table2[Table ID],
        AGGREGATE(
            15,
            6,
            (                ROW(
                    Table2[Table ID]
                ) -
                ROW(
                    Data!$A$2
                ) + 1 ) / ( Table2[Business Unit] = $C$9 ) * ( Table2[Close Date] >= $C$10 )
        ),
        ROWS(
            A$27:A27
        )
    )
)